# Symfony SncRedis Bundle exception handling if redis not available

Tags: php, exception, symfony, redis, bundle

I am using redis as a cache to help with application performance regarding data that has a high cost of generation. Currently we only have one redis instance running and I have observed that if redis is not available - then 500 error is being returned.

Given that I am caching - I would rather continue processing if redis is down and render that page with the data omitted.

I have tested using a basic php try - catch block - but it I have not been able to trap the exception.

```
public function redisAction()
{
  try {
    $redis = $this->container->get('snc_redis.default');
    $val = $redis->get('foo:bar');
  } catch (Exception $e ) {
    $response = new Response('Oops ');
    return $response;
  }
 ....
}
```

Is there any other approaches I can take - I am also investigating the sncredis bundle to see if it can be addressed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you did not include `use Exception` on top of your class you will need to add a leading backslash ... otherwise PHP will try to catch `Your\Current\Namespace\Exception` which doesn't exist.

```
catch (\Exception $e ) {
    // ...
}
```

But I'm not sure if redis throws an exception if the requested key does not exist (actually I don't think so).

You could use the `exists()` method to check if the key exists instead.

```
if ($redis->exists("foo:bar")) {
    return new Response('Oops');
}
```

Comment: Thanks - adding use Exception fixed the issue.